# Unable to perform aggregation and join with Mongo DB $lookup by Object ID

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Please find code fragment below

```
   db.collection('documents').aggregate([
     {
       $lookup:
        {
          from: 'pages',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'document_id',
          as: 'pages'
        }
    }])
```

Please find below sample document object with corresponding matching sample page

```
 SAMPLE DOCUMENT : 

 {"_id":"56d6b5c33bde388c1036216f","offername":"testoffer1", "details":{...} }

SAMPLE PAGE :

 { "_id":"23235c3sdsdc8c1036216f", "document_id":"56d6b5c33bde388c1036216f", "details":{} }
```

I am trying to group pages into the respective document using the `document_id` field in pages collection, to map with the `Object Id` in `documents` collection. But am getting empty array for pages despite there being matching data. However if I change the Object ID of documents collection to some other variable to match pages collection it works. Can someone help? I am assuming it has got something to do with the Object ID.

Comment: Can you post one documents and one pages object that have corresponding IDs? One other thought: Are the values in the document_id fields true ObjectId(...) objects, and not just strings?

Comment: @Christoph Yes the values in document_id fields are true ObjectId() objects as am not doing any explicit type casting. I had even tried '_id'.toString()  ,  '_id'.valueOf() , but still unresolved, Have updated the sample objects in question.

Comment: @Christoph  However I managed a workaround where I had to generate an alphanumeric key based on an algorithm and store it in a property say 'offer_id' in the document object and use it for matching with corresponding pages. This works fine. I guess the problem is with the datatype MongoDB Object ID. Will wait to hear from you on this. Thank you for your time.